# Android Kotlin - get data intent for age calculate

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin

the app should work like this : when i insert the year and month give me the result like : 2000 , 8 = 18 , 4 .. it's just give the month but the year not i think the problem is from startActivity i don't know what can i do am so beginner

```
// Get month and year birth

        val Get_year_input = age_year_input.text.toString().toInt()
        val getCurrentYear = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR)
        val finish_year_input = Get_year_input - getCurrentYear
        val Get_month_input = age_month_input.text.toString().toInt()
        val getCurrentMonth = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH)
        val finish_month_input = age_month_input.text.toString().toInt() - getCurrentMonth


        // Send Data
        val i_month = Intent(applicationContext, Second::class.java)
        val i_year = Intent(applicationContext, Second::class.java)
        i_month.putExtra("Month", finish_month_input)
        i_year.putExtra("Year", finish_year_input)

        startActivity(i_month)
        startActivity(i_year)
```

Second Activity :

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second)

    val finishMonthInput = intent.getIntExtra("Month", -1)
    val finishYearInput = intent.getIntExtra("Year", -2)

    viewYear.text = finishYearInput.toString()
    viewMonth.text = finishMonthInput.toString()

}

fun get_age_again(view: View){

    var backIntent = Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN")
    startActivity(backIntent)
}
```

Comment: `Get_year_input - getCurrentYear`. Current year will be greater than year input

Comment: Why are you launching two intents?

Comment: Put both extras to 1 intent

Comment: how ? i tried .. should i use StartActivites with array

Comment: // Send Data val i = Intent(applicationContext, Second::class.java)  i.putExtra("Month", finish_month_input) i.putExtra("Year", finish_year_input)  startActivity(i)

Answer (score 0):

In the first file:

```
 val Get_year_input = age_year_input.text.toString().toInt()
 val getCurrentYear = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR)
 val finish_year_input = Get_year_input - getCurrentYear
 val Get_month_input = age_month_input.text.toString().toInt()
 val getCurrentMonth = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH)
 val finish_month_input = age_month_input.text.toString().toInt() - getCurrentMonth
 // Send Data
 val i = Intent(applicationContext, Second::class.java)
 i.putExtra("Month", finish_month_input) 
 i.putExtra("Year", finish_year_input)
 startActivity(i)
```

You only need **one** intent. You are already using the key "Month" and "Year" to specify the name of the data, so need not use two intents.